# A Metacryptic Puzzle

Tags: cryptic-clues

Solve the 5 cryptic clues to reveal a final cryptic clue. Solve that one, too.

1. Stiff butt inside capital punishment, initially (5)
2. Blinded tin turned ton with ocean sound (6, 3)
3. Drink for Eastern victory (4)
4. Confused trope in pry land (8)
5. Playing E triad causes tantrum (6)

(7)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This answer shamelessly bundles the solutions others have found. I've contributed only the last missing answer and the meta answer. Definitions are in italics, solutions and wordplay in all caps.

1. Stiff butt inside capital punishment, initially (5)

> CRAMP – *stiff*; RAM (butt) inside CP (initial letters of capital punishment); found by TwoBitOperation

2. Blinded tin turned ton with ocean sound (6, 3)

> CANNOT SEE – *blinded*; CAN (tin) + TON< + SEA (homophone of sea)

3. Drink for Eastern victory (4)

> WINE – *drink*; WIN (victory) + E (Eastern); found by Sid

4. Confused trope in pry land (8)

> PROPERTY – *land*; anagram (confused) of TROPE in PRY; found by Chris Cudmore

5. Playing E triad causes tantrum (6)

> TIRADE – *tantrum*; anagram (playing) of E TRIAD; found by Sid

This yields the final clue:

> Cramp cannot see wine property tirade (7)

The solution to that meta clue is:

> RAMPAGE – *tirade*; [c]RAMP (cramp without C, "cannot see") + AGE (a property of wines as in "a 2012 Pinot Noir")

Thanks to all who have contributed partial answers!

Comment: You glorious *******!

Comment: Add the rest of the solutions here, credit the original solvers, and I'll serve your checkmark!

Comment: Great solve, awesome work!  Also, if you're right, it seems everyone who guessed was also right; yay teamwork!

Comment: @ChrisCudmore: Did you mean "Bachelor's late French child born out of wedlock (7)"?

Comment: Precisely! Yes.

Comment: @TwoBitOperation: Thanks. Were the guesses made in chat? I've come to the party late and haven't seen any guesses in comments.

Comment: @MOehm Oh, all I meant was that every person who offered up a partial answer was on the right track.  I haven't been to chat.

Answer (score 11):

**PARTIAL ANSWER:**

1. Stiff butt inside capital punishment, initially (5)

   > **CRAMP**. (Butt-Ram. Initials of Capital Punishment=CP. In means we get Cramp. Stiff is the def. (Thanks to @TwoBitOperation) [Note- I am not overly fond of this. But, yeah, it works..]
2. Blinded tin turned ton with ocean sound (6, 3)

   Not Answered
3. Drink for Eastern victory (4)

   > **WINE**. Victory-Win. Eastern- E. Drink-def.
4. Confused trope in pry land (8)

   > **PROPERTY** - Confused means anagram. Anagram of trope(Thanks to @Chris Cudmore, for pointing it out) in pry. Land is the def.
5. Inverted E triad gets angry (6)

   > Possibly **TIRADE** (Anagram of ETriad. Angry-def.)

Answer (score 10):

4. > P(ROPERT)Y - Confused TROPE in PRY.  Def: LAND

Answer (score 9):

PARTIAL GUESS:

1) Stiff butt inside capital punishment, initially (5)

> Stiff butt = Ram, in C.P. = **Cramp** (Stiff -def.)

Comment: Initially? How does that fit?

Comment: CP is the initials of capital punishment