# Metacryptic Puzzle (Part 1)

Tags: cryptic-clues

Okay, this is stolen from [Matt's Metacryptic puzzle.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47537/a-metacryptic-puzzle)

1. Former PM, a backless Camera with an opposing kill. (7)
2. Exertion without myself gets a headless era;Puzzling? (7)
3. Affection is the body of the toil mixed with the heartless villainy. (4)

7 is the number of letters of the final word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

final answer

> Cameron strange love (7)
>    →   **ROMANCE**    (Cameron strange [ROMANCE*]; love [*def.*])

Words found by **[@Chris Cudmore](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47918/30633)** (word 2)
  and **@Silenus** (words 1 & 3) in a now deleted answer:

> 1. **CAMERON**   (Former PM [*def.*]; a backless Camera [CAMER] + ...)
>                <s>... the completion is:  (+ opposing kill [NO< (vote)])</s>
>                ... OP's intention was:  (+ opposing kill [ON: *opposite* of "off"])
>
>  3. **LOVE**   (Affection [*def.*]; the body of the toil [(p)LO(d)]; heartless villainy [V(il)E or E(vi)L];
>              mixed with [ → LOVE])

Answer (score 0):

2.

> **STRANGE**  STRA (-i) N + (-a)GE