# Metametacryptic

Tags: cryptic-clues, metapuzzles

Inspired by [Matt's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20151/matt) [metacryptic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47537/a-metacryptic-puzzle) series, here's a *meta*metacryptic.

Solve the cryptic clues below to create two more clues. Solve those to create a final clue. Solve the final clue.

1. Impenetrable union loses nothing. Inform about big lie (14)
2. Stop after part of a right triangle key (6)
3. Street humor from an octopus's odor (5)

(5)

4. A great distance encircles the begetter (6)
5. Quickly oust and sadly die, subject to the elements (7)
6. Hopeless, both roam for toilet (8)
7. Pigpen, banks, or yarn (5)

(5)

(5)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Impenetrable union loses nothing. Inform about big lie (14)

> Unintelligible

Stop after part of a right triangle key (6)

> Legend

Street humor from an octopus's odor (5)

> Stink **( = St + ink)**

A great distance encircles the begetter (6)

> Father

Quickly oust and sadly die, subject to the elements (7)

> Outside **(anagram of oust and die)**

Hopeless, both roam for toilet (8)

> Bathroom

Pigpen, banks, or yarn (5)

> Story **(St(or)y)**

Then

> Unintelligible legend stink (5) = Greek **(G + reek)**

and

> Father outside bathroom story (5) = Floor **(F(loo)r)**

Finally

> Greek Floor (5) = Attic

So the final answer is

> **ATTIC**

Comment: Lovely! That completes all. +1 :)

Comment: Why is "Greek Floor" = "Attic"?

Comment: @justhalf An attic can be considered a floor in a house, specifically in the roof. Attic is also an adjective relating to ancient Athens, hence the Greek bit.

Answer (score 5):

**Partial**

1. Impenetrable union loses nothing. Inform about big lie (14)

> union loses nothing - UNION-O(zero) -> UNIN + TELL(inform) + INELIGIBLE(about big lie) -> **UNINTELLIGIBLE**(Impenetrable)

2. Stop after part of a right triangle key (6)

> Leg(part of right triangle) + end(stop) = **LEGEND** (key)

4. A great distance encircles the begetter (6)

> FAR(A great distance) + encircles the -> **FATHER**(begetter)

6. Hopeless, both roam for toilet (8)

> Anagram Ind(Hopless) -> both roam -> **BATHROOM** (for toilet)

Answer (score 5):

1.

> UNINTELLIGIBLE = Impenetrable = UNI-o-N loses nothing (UNIN). + Inform (TELL) + about BIG LIE (IGIBLE)

2.

> LEGEND thanks @Techidiot

3.

> Street (ST) + humor from an octopus's (INK) = STINK = odor

1,2,3.

> Unintelligible = GREEK = leG-end (G) stink (REEK)

4.

> FATHER thanks @Techidiot

5.

> Quickly oust (OUTS) + and sadly die (IDE) = OUTSIDE = subject to the elements (7)

6.

> BATHROOM thanks @Techidiot